# I’m finding water on the floor after washing

Tags: washing-machine, leaking

I had items on the floor in front of the washer get soaking wet but wasn’t sure why. Then I noticed my washing machine drum appears to tilt forward. I only noticed it because I got sprayed turning the water on to fill up when the water hit the back top of the drum causing it to spray so I’m guessing this happened during the cycle as well allowing water to pour down behind the drum and leak onto the floor possibly. Is this an easy DIY fix?

Comment: Depends on where/how it is leaking, the age of the machine (older can sometimes be easier/cheaper to fix than newer! but "rusted out" is harder to fix than "leaking replaceable valve") and other factors. Make/model of machine, pictures would help. And basically run through a few cycles until you track down where the leak is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.